# Accessing items from a dictionary within a tuple in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, tuples

Suppose I have a tuple along the lines of the following:

```
[('Cheeseburger', 'Entree', {'Buns': 1, 'Tomato': 1, 'Lettuce': 3, 'Onion': 1}), ('Salad', 'Entree', {'Buns': 0, 'Tomato': 2, 'Lettuce': 4, 'Onion': 3}), ...]
```

How could I access the values within the dictionary to add them up. The dictionary is within a list of tuples.

For example, I am looking for the sum for each food item (e.g., Cheeseburger: 6, Salad: 7).

Comment: Are you looking for the sum of all values in all dictionaries i.e. 14 in this case?

Comment: @ArkistarvhKltzuonstev sorry - fixed

Comment: @DarrylG sorry - fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can consider it as a multi-dimensional list
and access the elements

```
list = [('Cheeseburger', 'Entree', {'Buns': 1, 'Tomato': 1, 'Lettuce': 3, 'Onion': 1}),
    ('Salad', 'Entree', {'Buns': 0, 'Tomato': 2, 'Lettuce': 4, 'Onion': 2})]

for i in range (len(list)):
    for j in range (len(list[i])):
        if type(list[i][j]) == dict:
            x = list[i][j].items()
            # Remaing operations that you want to perform based on your need
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Assuming in each tuple the dictionary item is at index 2, you can simply do this :

```
food_list = [('Cheeseburger', 'Entree', {'Buns': 1, 'Tomato': 1, 'Lettuce': 3, 'Onion': 1}),
('Salad', 'Entree', {'Buns': 0, 'Tomato': 2, 'Lettuce': 4, 'Onion': 3}), ...]
food_dict = {k[0] : sum(k[2].values()) for k in food_list}
```